# How to graph variables values in a polar graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to graph a the values of a variable vs time in a polar graph countour (see the image of what i'm trying to do).

The emotion_list is the score for detected emotion

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

emotion_list = [0.0,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.0,0.2,0.0]

rad_arr = np.radians(np.arange(0,360,7))
r_arr = emotion_list
            
def func(r, theta):
    return r*np.sin(theta)
            
r, theta = np.meshgrid(r_arr, rad_arr)
print(r)
print(theta)
            
values = func(r, theta)
            
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection = 'polar'))
ax.contourf(theta, r, values, cmap = 'Spectral_r')
```

But the graphic i got is not as expected.

The graph i would like to is something like this:

[Graphic wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtcRo.png)

Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: What is the expected results. Also the MWE should be self containing, you have some undefined variables (emotion_list) and missing import statements. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips to get better answers.

Comment: Hello, something like the graph in this video , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qIlw36x7N6M&t=5s

Comment: The reason you don't get a plot like that is because your radial points are not monotonically increasing.  You have some repeated radial values which wont work well with a polar contour plot. If you change ```emotion_list = [0.0, 0.2, 0.3]``` and make other changes to make the shapes consistent, you will get a contour plot.

Answer (score 0):

A contour plot will not work well with repeated values. Try this

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

emotion_list = [0.0,0.2,0.3]

rad_arr = np.radians(np.arange(0,360,len(emotion_list)))
r_arr = emotion_list
            
def func(r, theta):
    return r*np.sin(theta)
            
r, theta = np.meshgrid(r_arr, rad_arr)
print(r)
print(theta)
            
values = func(r, theta)
            
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection = 'polar'))
ax.contourf(theta, r, values, cmap = 'Spectral_r')
plt.show()
```

The repeated values in `emotion_list` were removed and the shape of the `rad_arr` array is now connected to the length of the `emotion_list` array.

Comment: I tried what you told me but i didn't got the expected graphic behaviour. What i'm looking is: the emotions will be placed each 51º, i'm getting a list of emotion score (from 0 and 1), that will be the radious but how to assign the theta value for that score :(

Comment: I see, I now understand the relation to the video in your comment on the question. This question is more complex than I believe was originally asked and you should either edit the original question or ask a new one. I think your solution will need to include something along the lines of setting the value at a given point proportional to the number of times that point occurs. Although I am still not sure how you want to space the values through the angles.

Comment: Thanks @nikost, Well, the emotions will be distributed like this: len(emotion_list)/360.